# C# и нейронные сети. С чего начать и в какую сторону смотреть?

Tags: c#, opencv, нейронные-сети, обработка-изображений

Вопрос довольно общий, знаю.

Но я здесь немного уточню что бы было не так расплывчасто.

1. Интересует общая сжатая теория. С какой статьи лучше начать?
2. Интересуют актуальные библиотеки C#
3. Интересует приблизительная реализация уже созданной в нескольких вариациях идеи -- скармливаешь нейронке много изображений-пар: большое и маленькое. А нейронка учится делать из маленького большое и потом сравнивает сделанное большое и то большое которое ему скормили что бы понять что сделано не так. Какую нейронку лучше выбрать под даную задачу?
4. Не слишком ли сложная и на сколько вообще реальная задачка в 3, если учесть что я вообще ни бум-бум в нейронных сетях?
5. Если задача непосильная для новичка в НС, то с каких задач-тренировок лучше начинать?

Comment: пытаюсь понять что имеется в виду "делает из маленкого большое" :-) уже ж есть и большие и маленькие, где кому и за сколько надо еще их делать? Или вы хотите так натренировать систему, чтобы она потом из любой маленькой делала большую хорошего качества - не понимаю

Comment: именно так и хочу сделать. Большую нужно что бы НС могла сравнивать результат своей работы с оригиналом. И это что-то вроде фидбека по тому на сколько качественно сделанная работа.

Comment: а вы думаете что НС справится с этим лучше чем алгоритмы image scaling - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling ??

Comment: Именно так. Лучшие решения которые я видел по результатам -- являлись НС решениями. Одно дело просто скейлить изображение, а совсем иное -- сначала отскейлить и потом "дорисовывать" изображение деталям взятыми с других фотографий на основе опыта НС.

Comment: Что бы понять про что я говорю -- попробуй просто отскейлить картинку, а потом попробуй закинуть ее же в http://waifu2x.udp.jp/ . А потом уже будешь рассказыать на сколько алгоритм скейла лучше справляется с работой чем НС :) Отдельно попробуй на нескольких фотках и отдельно на нескольких рисованых картинках.

Comment: Не ну я охотно верю в силу мысли и что всё можно сделать лучще :-) Удачи!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Одна из самых изысканных задач для НС приведена в [этой статье](https://picoledelimao.github.io/blog/2016/01/31/is-it-a-cat-or-dog-a-neural-network-application-in-opencv/), можно понять уровень проблематики и алгоритмов, которые задействуются для решений подобного класса задач и где действительно нужна НС. Примеры на [OpenCV](http://opencv.org), что тоже замечательно.

OpenCV - Библиотека с самой открытой лицензией и исходным кодом, написана на C++. Под C# есть wrapper'ы - [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), [OpenCV for Unity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088) (можно и без Unity использовать). 
Есть адаптация для Visual Studio (C++), Objective C, Android Studio, Python.

Даже для умеренно сложных задач НС обычно не нужна, и не очень даже применима - часто приходится делать обработку видеопотока в реальном времени, а НС не самая быстрая штука далеко. По этой и еще ряду причин большинство разработчиков, уверенных поначалу что им нужна НС, от этой идеи впоследствии отказываются. 
Благо в OpenCV реализовано огромное количество алгоритмов на все случаи жизни - почти всё, что связано с обработкой видео и изображений там есть.

**После редактирования автором вопроса редактирую ответ :-)**

Большинство [алгоритмов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling), реализованных в доступных пакетах, в основном предназначены для down-scaling, спрос на это очевиден - камера снимает в большом разрешении, а в [Интернеты](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B) лучше постить, предварительно уменьшив фотку - этим пользуются все активные пользователи Интернетов и соцсетей.

Up-scaling задача тоже достаточно хорошо проработана, просто спрос на нее несоизмеримо меньше - тем не менее любой дизайнер отлично знает, что нужно делать, чтобы изображение можно было без проблем увеличивать - взять Corel Draw или другой пакет векторной графики, то есть сделать изображение **векторным**.

Таким образом, если маленькое растровое изображение преобразовать в векторы, сделать up-scaling, мы скорее всего уже получим что-то интересное - обратите внимание на программу [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/). В OpenCV готового для raster->vector ничего нет. Хотя из доступных инструментов и можно слепить что-то, врядли получится лучше чем у Potrace - всё-таки там люди занимались этой проблемой специально. Potrace идёт с исходниками и подробным описанием алгоритмов, так что простор для творчества полный :-)

И самое интересное на десерт - пора взглянуть на ваше увеличенное изображение, и путем сравнения с полученным в результате векторизации и up-scaling результатом выявить отклонения. Выявленные отклонения могут являться материалом для обучения НС. Например, можно пойти путем векторизации большого изображения, выявления соответствия кривых и сравнения их характеристик. По результатам обучения НС начнет выдавать некие рекомендации по коррекции кривых в произвольных изображениях. 
Может быть даже замахнуться на добавление кривых, типа дополнительных цветовых контуров градиента (хотя градиент в полученном изображении проще будет сгладить с помощью функций Blur и т.п.)

Comment: Ну это неплохой подход для изображений растовых, но картинок. А как насчет фото?

Comment: фото чем не растровая картинка? :)

Comment: Растрирование фотографии по факту дат далеко не такой качественный результат, как в случае с рисованой картинки. Так же утрачается, скажем, текстура кожи. Было бы круто на основе опыта скормленных картинок раньше рисовать более детализированную кожу нужного оттенка. Теоретически это реально.

Comment: растровые форматы = пиксельные форматы - png, jpg, .... не важно что там фотка или рисованное что-то, дизайнеры вполне успешно делают в векторах изображения на основе растровых фото, чтобы печатать это на больших рекламных баннерах например

Comment: да, знаю. :) Возможно криво написал. С большими рекламными банерами проще. Никто их не рассматривает достаточно близко :) Если присмотришься вблизи к таким банерам -- увидишь особенности печати таких банеров. Там вкрапления краски идут довольно большого размера. Вроде "круглых пикселей". Т.к. точное изображение не требуется, все равно смотрят лишь издалека. А издалека эти неточности смазываются.

Comment: Если изображение представлено качественно в векторах - пиксели будут появляться исключительно из-за особенностей типографского оборудования а не качества картинки. Типичный пример хорошего векторного изображения - шрифты True Type или Open Type - сколько не увеличивай всё равно плавные и гладкие :-)

Comment: впрочем отчасти вы правы - при преобразовании фото в векторы и дальнейшем существенном масштабировании могут появляться неестественные монотонные области, но это уже легко сгладить существующими простыми инструментами - типа Median Blur, Gaussian Blur и т.п.

Comment: А первая ссылка то не рабочая. Может есть новая?

Answer (score 8):

1. Если хотите изучить математический аппарат нейронных сетей, то рекомендую начать с изучения перцептрона. Найти статьи по этому типу ИНС несложно.
2. С библиотеками по нейронным сетям на C# довольно плохо дела обстоят. Для C# лучшая, на мой взгляд, библиотека от Microsoft - Microsoft cognitive toolkit. (https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki). Из минусов: нельзя обучать и строить модель сети в коде C#/.NET и пока реализация в бета-версии, так что могут быть баги. Из плюсов: легко строить различные сети с помощью скриптового языка Brainscript, есть поддержка вычислений/обучения модели на GPU от nVidia (на C#/.NET можно только вычислять), поддерживаются различные типы нейронных сетей.
   На гитхабе в разделе Wiki можете найти всю интересующую вас информацию и примеры для реализации ИНС с помощью Microsoft cognitive toolkit в C#. Ещё можете посмотреть нейронные сети в математическом фреймворке Accord, но, насколько я помню, там не очень много возможностей и вычисления доступны только на ЦП.
3. Конкретно для данной задачи я бы применил свёрточную нейронную сеть. http://engineering.flipboard.com/2015/05/scaling-convnets здесь даже можете посмотреть примерную архитектуру такой сети для поставленной вами задачи.
4. Если нейронную сеть с нуля не собираетесь писать, то вполне посильная :)
5. Попробуйте изучить для начала многослойный перцептрон и реализовать его, например для решения задачи XOR.

Answer (score 3):

Дополню предыдущие ответы относительно [CNTK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/). Недавно вышедшая версия 2.2 имеет уже полноценный биндинг к C#. Соответственно, можно не только применять, но и обучать сеть, не переключаясь на Python или BrainScript.